# Ajax: setInterval function doesn't update html (but it works)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several `div`s in code. I need to update the html inside, based on API request.
It works, but html doesn't refresh (i.e. if I get via API a new result, html remain same of first iterate, but in firebug I can read new HTML ready to inject in page).

```
$('div.show-gpio-state').each(function(i, obj) {
        var id_gpio = $(this).data('id-gpio');
        getGpioState(id_gpio,$(this));
        setInterval(function(){getGpioState(id_gpio,$(this))}, 5000);
    });

function getGpioState(id_gpio,box) {

    $.ajax(
            {   url: api_gpio_url+id_gpio,
                cache:false,
                success: function (result) {
                    box.html('');
                    var state = result;
                    var final_state = '';
                    if ( (state==='error') || (state==='') ) {
                        final_state = '<span class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>';
                    } else {
                        if (state==1) {
                            final_state = '<p class="h2"><i class="fa fa-fire text-success"></i></p>';
                        } else {
                            final_state = '<p class="h2"><i class="fa fa-remove text-grey"></i></p>';
                        }
                    }
                box.html('');
                box.html(final_state);
                // here in console I have right final state for right box
                console.log(final_state);
                console.log(box);

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Why are you testing for failure in your success callback? Why not just accept the result and inject it where it should go and set up a second error callback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
setInterval(function(){getGpioState(id_gpio,$(this))}, 5000);
```

to

```
setInterval(function(){getGpioState(id_gpio,$(this))}.bind(this), 5000);
```

or assign `$(this)` to variable and pass inside setInterval function

Comment: The reasons that works is the function scope of `this`, because inside the `setInterval` you defining a new function with it's own scope. So `this` will refer to the `setInterval`-function instead of jQuery `each` function

Answer (score 1):

You could fix it like:

```
setInterval((function(_this){
  return function(){
    getGpioState(id_gpio,$(_this));
  };
}(this)), 5000);
```

The issue is related to how `scope` and `this` keyword works in JavaScript.

Or you could even simply use a variable:

```
$('div.show-gpio-state').each(function(i, obj) {
    var id_gpio = $(this).data('id-gpio');
    var $this = $(this);
    getGpioState(id_gpio,$this);
    setInterval(function(){getGpioState(id_gpio,$this)}, 5000);
});
```

To learn more about the issue you could read this post: [Understand JavaScript’s “this” With Clarity, and Master It](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)